# Fullcalendar Scheduler TimelineWeek event spans for the whole day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, scheduler

On the timelineWeek view every event spans for the entire column width. [(snapshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCemm.png)

```
$.fullCalendar({
...
        week: {
            minTime: '00:00',
            slotDuration: '24:00',
            slotLabelFormat: 'ddd D MMM',
            slotLabelInterval: '24:00',
        },
...
```

With some magic numbers I can get *closer* of what I'm looking for, since the events do not span. However if I do this I get Sunday two times... ([snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJSsh.png))

```
            minTime: '00:00',
            slotDuration: '23:59',
            slotLabelFormat: 'ddd D MMM',
            slotLabelInterval: '23:59',
```

Do any of you guys know a way of achieving something like this, you know, with some proper code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm sticking with this magic number.

```
minTime: '00:00',
slotDuration: '24:00',
slotLabelFormat: 'ddd D MMM',
slotLabelInterval: '23:59:59.999', // magic
```

It seems to be working, but it makes me feel guilty. If you have a better solution please let me know!

Thanks